# card reader не читается

Tags: linux

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с тем, что в линукс не читаются карты памяти SD? Само устройство определяется, но при вставке карты в лоток ничего не происходит, даже после перезапуска системы. Может кто подскажет что можно сделать?

Comment: Какой дистрибутив? Какая версия ядра? Читались ли раньше или началось только недавно? По больше бы информации.

Comment: У меня часто такая же проблема. Kubuntu 11.04. Монтирую руками. Самому не досуг разобраться.

Comment: Как руками монтируете? Дистрибутив ubuntu 11.10. На винде всё работает, на ubuntu 11.04 тоже работала, даже не приходилось ничего дополнительно делать, тут как-будто "мертва"...

Comment: В трее появляется значек ЮСБ устройства, ПКМ и монтировать. Я у себя выбираю "Отменить скрытие устройств", а затем монтирую. Просто проверьте параметры монтирования внешних носителей. И другие карты или переходники пробовали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файловая система на SD карте быть может та которая не распознается.. какой дистр, ФС и пр. инфу в студию

Comment: Не знаю как у автора, у меня такая проблема с фат.